# "The custom type is invalid" error in bitrix24 REST API

Tags: python, bitrix

I am working on the bitrix24 REST API. I am able to get the 200 response from other API like crm.contact.add, crm.deal.add. When I am using the crm.contact.userfield.add It gives the error of "The custom type is invalid". Hence I need to know what to change in the API. I have changed the fields[FIELD_NAME] values and tried. But it gives the same error.

The purpose of this API is to add the additional custom fields to the CRM.

I tried with python's Bitrix24 module and getting the same error.

```
URL: https://b24-fnhdps.bitrix24.com/rest/crm.contact.userfield.add/?
fields[USER_TYPE_ID]=93&fields[FIELD_NAME]=Customer&fields[SETTINGS][DEFAULT_VALUE]=Dominion
&auth={auth}.
```

I am getting below error.

```
{
    "error": "ERROR_CORE",
    "error_description": "The custom type is invalid.<br>"
}.
```

Source: https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/crm/contacts/crm_contact_userfield_add.php

Please help me to sort out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issues. In the REST API, there is a parameter field[USER_TYPE_ID]. What I was passing is the ID of the CRM Contact. Actually, that should be the type of field. Hence the value of field[USER_TYPE_ID] is just string. Below is the working API.

```
URL: https://b24-fnhdps.bitrix24.com/rest/crm.contact.userfield.add/?
fields[USER_TYPE_ID]=string&fields[FIELD_NAME]=Customer&fields[SETTINGS][DEFAULT_VALUE]=Dominion
&auth={auth}.
```